# Environment variable in Azure function is not retrieved

Tags: azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure function. It should retrieve some environment variables values like this:

```
   string username = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process) ?? _config["BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME"] ?? _config["Values:BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME"];
```

For local testing, the variables are set in local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
     "BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME": "Set in Azure. For development, set in User Secrets (secrets.json)",
  ...
  }
}
```

In Azure, I set corresponding variables in the release pipeline:

```
- stage: Production
dependsOn: QA
variables:
- group: Production
```

[image]

Everything seems to be in place, and yet when I run the Azure function via Postman, the username is null. What can I be missing?

Comment: what your screenshot shows in a variable group in Azure DevOps, that is not the configuration of your Azure Function

Comment: @silent OK, but it is an environment variable, right? Why can't I retrieve it using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()?

Comment: it is available an env var inside your build agent. But you need to configure your Azure Function deployment task to pass whatever config vars you want to have there

Comment: @silent Maybe you could refer me to some documentation I could use to do that?

Comment: Assuming you use the Function Deploy task, look for appSettings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-function-app?view=azure-devops

Comment: @silent Great, thank you, it worked. Would you like to make this an answer? I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables from ADO are available as env vars inside your build agent. But you need to configure your Azure Function deployment task to pass whatever config vars you want to have there.

Assuming you use the Function Deploy task, look for `appSettings`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-function-app?view=azure-devops